# Why is flexbox's first child taking more space than its own content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.w {
  width: 10rem;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.c {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*align-items: flex-start;*/
  align-items: stretch;
}

.v {
    /*align-self: flex-start;*/
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: blue;
}

.t {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="c">
    <div class="v">
        <div class="t"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d">
      <div>el1</div>
      <div>el2</div>
      <div>el3</div>
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

How to ensure `div.v` takes exactly the same amount of space as `div.t` (which **has a set size**), while leaving `div.d` grow based on its content?

The current result is as follows:

[image: actual result]

Expected result: (edited)

[image]

https://codepen.io/manuWebFE/pen/poPMLze

Comment: Remove the `width: 100%;`?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `widht: 100%` from `.v` class

```css
.w {
  width: 10rem;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.c {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*align-items: flex-start;*/
  align-items: stretch;
}

.v {
    /*align-self: flex-start;*/
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: blue;
}

.t {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="c">
    <div class="v">
        <div class="t"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d">
      <div>el1</div>
      <div>el2</div>
      <div>el3</div>
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```